# Temporary R minimal environment

Tags: r, installation, environment

I have 100+ Linux servers that I want to run R code on for analysis or whatever.  Installing R on each and every one of them I think is unfeasible.  So I am wondering if it's possible to push a temporary R environment over to each one, run my code, produce my reports, and then tear down the R environment when complete.

I probably only need a minimal R environment for this purpose.

Any pointers would be much appreciated! Thanks.

TIM

Comment: In which way is pushing a temporary R environment to 100 server more feasible than installing R 100 times? Which Linux by the way?

Comment: pssh allows you to send commands to all the servers at once. Maybe it would help.

Comment: The tools you use to manage your servers (puppet, chef, etc. -- you should mention which one(s) you are using) 
should allow you to install (and uninstall) software without any trouble.

Comment: @Beasterfield We have a system already that can push a script or whatever over to the Linux boxes. So I'm thinking my script will include an R package and within my code I can unpack R onto the box, execute my code, and then remove R from the box. This is better than maintaining 100 separate R installations.

Comment: @Beasterfield Sorry, this is RHEL5

Comment: I don't know what you mean with *minimal R environment* or how this is different from a base R installation, but when you say you have already an infrastructure for pushing commands to your boxes, why not just sending `yum install R` to them and when you're done `yum remove R`?